# In the parallel structure, should I omit "become" if the subject is noun

Tags: grammaticality

(1) The deeper the river becomes, the greater the danger is.
(2) The deeper the river, the greater the danger.
(3) The deeper the river becomes, the greater the danger.
(4) The deeper the river, the greater the danger is.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Choice 1 seems to contemplate the changing depth of one river. Choice 2 seems to compare two rivers with different depths, without suggesting that any one river is changing. Choices 3 and 4 seem open to the same analysis. This is not a grammatical error, just a different connotation.

Comment: Stylistically, I don't like Choice 4, which has a verb in just the second part. My preference is for Choice 2, then 1, 3 and 4, although my favorite has no verb at all and seems to be a sentence fragment, strictly speaking.

Comment: All are close enough to being syntactically correct (I'm sure someone can nitpick though).  It's mostly a question of style.

Comment: I think all of these are grammatical. I don't like the way (3) and (4) sound, if you want a verb at the end, make it *becomes* or *gets*, but none is required. As noted above the meaning changes with different phrasing. If you want to give (incorrect) advice about the danger of various rivers, say *The deeper the river, the greater the danger* so we know that deep rivers are more dangerous than shallow ones. If you want to give information about the evolution of one river, say, *As the river gets deeper, the danger increases* (or *gets greater*).

Comment: @MikeGraham Quite. But why not simply - "The deeper the river gets, the greater the danger".

Comment: Choice (2) is punchiest and probably the most idiomatic. It's such a common construction (_the bigger, the better_ and examples with added noun groups) that few would worry about the extragrammatical nature. Context would indicate whether or not one river or many were being referenced. (1) uses a true sentence and is a more formal choice. But it's not directly comparing several rivers. (3) and (4) are unbalanced, but I'd say that (4) sounds much better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's fine if you are simply stating a general principle - "the deeper the river, the greater the danger". However if you are managing the ongoing response to a flood, standing there in your Wellington boots with one eye on the weather forecast and another on the water level, you may wish to point out to the people controlling the locks downriver of you, that "the deeper the river gets, the greater the danger".

Comment: @WS2 I think 'higher' is the correct usage there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, so it's a ford. And, still in your Wellingtons, you are a local worthy on the phone to the police, urging them to block the road and set up detour notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a history to parallelisms like this, in which the verb *to be* or some other verb is omitted.  The omission itself was almost an announcement like a roll of drums:  "this is a universal truth".  This style of expression was called in ancient Greece *αποφθεγμα* (*apophthegm* - pronounced *apofthem*).  The pre-socratic proponent of an early version of atomic theory, Demokritos, wrote (on another topic):

> "The world (cosmos) a stage set life a chorus entry you came you saw you left" .  We can't go quite that far in leaving out verbs.  A couple of centuries later, the Alexandrian poet Callimachus, rebelling against traditional epic poetry, in favour of short, lighter so-called 'mini-epic' (*epyllion* - *επυλλιον*) declared, portentously:-
>
> Μεγα βιβλιον μεγα κακον (*Big book, big evil/trouble/bore* - he probably meant all three at once).

What is the 'grammar' of this?  In the Demokritos saying it's easy.  We are left to assume the (unstated) verb *is*.  The cosmos **is** a stage set.  So you could say that there is a verb, and so the word string does constitute a sentence, but one with an ellipse. By the convention of apophthegms we are allowed not to bother with the copula.

But with Callimachus' declaration of rebellion, what is the verb here?  You could say "is":  a big book **is** a big bore.  There are sayings like this in English, not least the those concerning big feet and those, conversely and more topically, concerning small hands.  What we have here is the 'grammar' of juxtaposition, which we understand without putting it into words:  *big/small A implies/goes together with big/small B*; or you could say *show me big/small A and I'll show you big/small B*; or that ***if (or where) you find***big/small A, **then/there you will also find** big/small B.  There doesn't have to be a particular verb at all.  Similarly with the ancient pithy apophthegm *nothing too much* (*μηδεν αγαν / meeden agan*). You can say that we are expected to think the verb *do* and so complete a grammatical imperative sentence, something like "Don't do anything to excess".  In English, we say "moderation in all things".  Is this a *sentence fragment*?  If you like, you can call it that, but in that case you also have to say that there are sentence fragments with which there is nothing wrong.

Which brings me to your example:

> The deeper the river, the greater the danger.

I should say that it is a proverb, like the ancient apophthegm, and that, like the apophthegm, it does not need a verb.  Any *'proper'* sentence is weaker than the pithy *proverbial* structure.

> For any river, the danger  increases in proportion to its depth.